# Tomcat server is running but Application is not running

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am facing a problem like, my tomcat server is running okay, but once I opening the application, it's showing 404 error.
The maven build is successful of the application and I deployed the .war file manually in webapps folder. I am clicking on startup.bat under bin folder. My server startup port is 8082. 
Please find the screen attached below and provide a suggestion.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykYiz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsT2E.jpg)

Comment: Usually there is an error in starting up the application, and then it will not be available and you get  a 404. (Sorry, but I cannot see your screenshots because that image site is blocked at my place.)

Comment: @gsl ,, thanks, The images are the one that the tomcat server is up, and the other one is the application is getting 404 error.
Yes the application is not starting up. I don't know no if the system environment is the reason. I have used different jdks, jdk-1.6.23 upto jdk-1.0.8.152.
In the log I'm getting: **SEVERE: Context [/sample-web] startup failed due to previous errors**

Comment: What is in tomcats log? I mean, apart from "startup failed...". Before that line any hints?

Comment: @gsl,,, below exception line I found in the _LOG file_ ;  SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.nrift.finch.inf.startup.web.OperationContextListener
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: application init failed** . OperationContextListner is implementing **ServletContextListener** interface. But I think the context initialization is not the actual issue. 
thanks.

Comment: The exception in the initialization of your webapp in that OperationContextListener is the reason your application cannot be started! Have a look what might be going wrong there. Is there a log of this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename and place your war file as ROOT.war and remove existing ROOT.war, directory ROOT in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps ,then restart the tomcat service

if the problem still persists then please display your tomcat logs from /usr/local/tomcat/logs

Comment: Hi,, I can not find any existing **ROOT.war** file in apache tomcat 7 server. There is ROOT directory which contains logo icons and build.xml under webapps folder. I renamed the previous war file and placed it inside webapps, but problem remains same. The log is as mentioned above.
I am thinking of changing jdk-8 to jdk-7.0.45 ,, and redeploy the war file again.